# How to consolidate two audio files on client side. (Maybe even server side)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, audio-recording, wavesurfer.js

(Working in React.js)

Hello developer folks.  I'm developing a musical chat application right now where the user can listen to an audio file and then should be able to record over that audio file. The logic consolidates the first audio file and the over-dub together so the user can then send the consolidated audio to an other user.

The audio shall be sent to my server (MongoDB) - where the file will then be stored and distributed to user2.

I'm looking for the easiest way to do that.

For playback of audio files in the chat I'm using wavesurfer.js.

I have not found a lot about consolidating audio files and thought someone hier might know something.

Thank you in advance and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this npm Package https://www.npmjs.com/package/crunker. 
Does just what I want :-)